# How to pass data from one view controller to another view controller which is embedded in navigation controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I was able to pass data from one view controller to another, but when I embedded viewpapersViewController in navigation controller, data is not passing,
I want to pass data to second view controller when button is pressed

originally when button is pressed a request is sent, then in connectionDidFinishLoading

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

  // NSLog(@"Finish Loading");
NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self->_responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];


Papers *papersViewController =
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Papers"];
papers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
urls=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(id key in res) {

    NSString* name = [key objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString* url =[key objectForKey:@"url"];

    [papers addObject:name];
    [urls addObject:url];

}

viewpapersViewController.exam = exam;
viewpapersViewController.papersName=papers;
viewpapersViewController.urls=urls;

[self presentViewController:viewpapersViewController animated:YES completion:Nil];

}
```

Comment: Can you explain or provide examples of what you have tried? How were you originally passing the data?

Comment: show your code, we are not telepathist to identify an error in your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to pass a string,You can simply pass your data by these steps:-

1- Go on second view controller and take a  -- NSString *str;

2- And when you are pressing a button from your first view controller directly pass the data
    like : - secondClassObject.str = FirstClassString.
  3- And then Push your Navigation simply.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we will pass data two ways:

1. We just instantiate the target **UIViewController** and then pass the data to its properties.
2. Another way we use is segue. Essentially, it's the same with the first way.

For your problem, what I could think of is you are not getting your **UIViewController** right.
You can probably try to get the **UINavigationController** first.
Then, use this property to access the top UIViewController: `topViewController`

Answer (score 0):

If you have ViewController connected with same Navigation Controller . You must have performed  PUSH Segue from 1st View to 2nd View by Drag from 1st to 2nd View. Click Push option in that . You have set up the Push Segue by this .

Give a name to identifier to segue by clicking on that link between the 2 Views .

Now you can perform simple Segue by

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier for segue" sender:self];
```

Now in 1st View

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"identifier segue"]){
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    2nd View *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    2nd vc.variableName  = YES;
}}
```

In 2nd View in interface file 
add property

```
@property variable *variableName;
```